# Rename node.js sequelize timestamp columns

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I've just started using sequelize but I'm having a small issue mapping an existing database.

By default sequelize creates two datatime columns named createdAt and updatedAt, does anyone know if its possible to rename the columns to something else. For example...

```
products: sequelize.define('products', {
    timestamps: false,
    product_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        primaryKey: true, 
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    product_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    product_description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    product_created: Sequelize.DATE,
    product_updated: Sequelize.DATE
}),
```

That would still automagically amend the product_created/product_updated columns on creates and updates.

Comment: Maybe this? `renameColumn(tableName, attrNameBefore, attrNameAfter)   

This methods allows renaming attributes.

    migration.renameColumn('Person', 'signature', 'sig')`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Another update strikes (and two years pass) and you can do just what [you want](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/models/):

```js
products: sequelize.define('products', {
    timestamps: false,
    product_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
        primaryKey: true, 
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    product_name: Sequelize.STRING,
    product_description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    product_created: Sequelize.DATE,
    product_updated: Sequelize.DATE
}, {
  updatedAt: 'product_updated',
  createdAt: 'product_created'
});
```

Comment: Good news, sadly the project i was working on at the time is well out of the door, but good to know for the future!

Comment: @OliverRidgway I know its not kind to the previous guy, but could you mark this answer as correct answer for future ref?

Comment: Sure, poor Sascha, gave us sequelize and now we're taking reputation off him!

Comment: @OliverRidgway if only there was a way to transfer reputation... I am ashamed of myself.

Answer (score 0):

sadly this is not yet possible. Can you please open an issue on github. I guess this is pretty easy to implement.

Thanks :)